# Set-PnPListItemPermission and Set-PnPListPermission - Does this send out a notification to the user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I couldn't find in the docs if this was the case or not, I assume not, but I just want to make sure (and I have no test users to test with):

If I use `Set-PnPListItemPermission` or `Set-PnPListPermission` to grant someone say Contribute access, does this give a notification to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't send out emails.

It is not supported by the code-behind as well.

You can checkout the code behind, it uses the CSOM methods to set permissions which dont trigger mails.

Github - [SetListPermission](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/Lists/SetListPermission.cs)

Github - [SetListItemPermission](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/Lists/SetListItemPermission.cs)

Comment: Good to know! I just wanted to confirm. I'm doing a bulk update on permissions and I don't want all these notifications to fire off.